# Reposition nav buttons inside owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

i am using owl carousel and i want to change the default nav buttons "prev next" with arrows and place them on the right side and left side in carousel. 
See the picture:

https://postimg.org/image/w4od5pb2z/

http://raffe.ro/bogdan.v/one-page/

Here is the js code:

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 3000,
      smartSpeed: 900,
      autoplayHoverPause: false,
      loop: true,
      margin: 30,
      nav: false,
      dotsEach: true,
      touchDrag: true,
      dotData: true,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1
        },
        600: {
          items: 1
        },
        1000: {
          items: 1

        }
      }

    })
  }) <
  /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post relevant HTML and CSS in the question in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the code snippet feature. Do not post images of code (no clue if yours has code as I can't see it) or links to your website which make the question useless for future users ones the site changes and/or might contain unsafe material, spam or worse (We don't know that) [**Why not to upload Images of Code when asking a Question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code in your css (style.css):

```
.owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-nav .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}

.owl-nav .owl-next {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

In theory, it should work